# Como resolver problema de layout do errorText em Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout

Eu estou tendo uma certa dificuldade com o errorText do TextFormField.
Sempre que aparece ele "empurra" os outros elementos pra baixo.

O que eu uso é basicamente essa estrutura:

```
Scaffold( 
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade100, 
      body: Center( 
        child: Form( 
          key: _formKey, 
          child: Container( 
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0), 
            width: 400, 
            height: 200, 
            decoration: BoxDecoration( 
              color: Colors.white, 
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), 
            ), 
            child: Column( 
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
              children: [ 
                TextFormField( 
                  decoration: const InputDecoration( 
                    labelText: 'Nome', 
                    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always, 
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, right: 3, top: 14, bottom: 14), 
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, height: 0.1), 
                  ), 
                  validator: (value) { 
                    if(value == null || value == '') { 
                      return 'Campo não pode ser vazio'; 
                    } 
                  }, 
                ), 
                const SizedBox(height: 24,), 
                SizedBox( 
                  width: 80, 
                  height: 35, 
                  child: ElevatedButton( 
                    onPressed: () { 
                      _formKey.currentState!.validate(); 
                    }, 
                    child: const Text('Validar') 
                  ), 
                ), 
              ] 
            ), 
          ), 
        ), 
      ), 
    ); 
  }
```

Comment: Fala Nelson. A resposta que foi fornecida resolveu seu problema? Se sim, acha que pode aceitá-la? Você pode fazer isso clicando no símbolo de ✔️ ao lado da resposta. Fazer isso contribui com a categorização e eventuais buscas no site. Um abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Esta é uma dúvida que já foi discutida no [repositório](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15400) oficial do Flutter (em inglês, um tempo atrás).

O erro ocorre porque a altura que o Widget calcula para si é diferente caso ele possua ou não uma mensagem de erro a ser exibida.

Foram citadas duas soluções:

- Adicione um `helperText` **vazio** (Isto é, um espaço: `" "`), utilizando o mesmo estilo que o seu `errorText`. Desta forma o Widget vai calcular sua altura levando em consideração o texto inferior e não vai ser diferente da altura de quando a mensagem de erro aparece:

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    helperText: ' ', // Helper text como uma string contendo um espaço.
    helperStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, height: 0.1), // O mesmo que o usado em errorStyle
```

- Envolva o seu `TextFormField` em um outro Widget com uma altura fixa (como um `SizedBox`). É importante que essa altura fixa seja maior do que o tamanho que o TextFormField ocupa. Em meus testes, `70` foi suficiente:

```dart
children: [
    SizedBox(
        height: 70,
        child: TextFormField( // Seu TextFormField aqui.
```

Ambas as soluções atingem o resultado desejado. Você pode escolher a que melhor se adequa:

A primeira tem como vantagem o fato de ser uma altura dinâmica. Você não precisa se preocupar em escolher arbitrariamente um valor para a altura, como precisa fazer na segunda solução. O `TextFormField` terá sempre sua altura justinha e exata. Se no futuro algo externo mudar, pode ser que a altura escolhida no segundo método não seja mais adequada. Você pode experimentar mudar a altura para um valor pequeno e ver o que acontece.

Em contra partida, a primeira solução "parece" um pouco mais como uma gambiarra. Pode atrapalhar a legibilidade, e vai precisar de uma lógica pequena caso você queira usar um `helperText` também. Em um futuro, caso outra pessoa (ou você mesmo) leia essa linha, pode não ser claro a necessidade do espaço em branco.